# Split numbers and letters in a string Python

Tags: python

How would I split numbers and letters in a string? So if given:

```
string = "12really happy15blob"

splitString = []
splitString = mySplitter(string) 
print splitString
```

would return `["12","really happy","15","blob"]`

Comment: Because *this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*, as the tooltip says.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `re.split` here:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'(\d+)', "12really happy15blob")
['', '12', 'really happy', '15', 'blob']
```

Note that you actually get an empty string from splitting between the start of the string and the initial `12`.  You'd have to filter that out if you didn't want it.

Comment: @iCodez -- Yes, but only for this example.  `'foo12bar'` wouldn't have an empty string at the front.  More generally, you'd probably just post process the output,  Something akin to:  `[x for x in output if x]` which would also remove trailing empty strings from `'foobar12'` for example.

Comment: The line `re.findall(r'(\d+|\D+)', "12really happy15blob")` does it without the leading empty string.